# I want to disable other/different row based on current row value in InitializeRow event of UltraWinGrid

Tags: c#, gridview, grid, infragistics

For disabling a row in UltraWinGrid I know we can use this logic

e.Row.Activation = Activation.NoEdit or  e.Row.Activation = Activation.Disabled

But I want to disable other row based on current row values.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code to better describe what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can reach other rows in the grid by traversing the current row RowsCollection, go to the child bands rows' RowsCollections, or go to the parent row's RowsCollection. To reach any of these collections you can use code like this in InitializeRow event:

```
   private void UltraGrid1_InitializeRow(object sender, InitializeRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //  Get the current row RowsCollection
        var currentRowsCollection = e.Row.ParentCollection;

        //  Get the current row child bands rows collections
        if(e.Row.ChildBands != null)
        {
            foreach(UltraGridChildBand childBand in e.Row.ChildBands)
            {
                var childRowsCollection = childBand.Rows;
            } 
        }

        //  Get the parent row RowsCollection
        if(e.Row.HasParent())
        {
            var parentRowsCollection = e.Row.ParentRow.ParentCollection;
        }
    }
```

After reaching the necessary rows collection you can get the row you need by index.
However doing this in InitializeRow event could be a little tricky, as you may have GroupByRows, SummaryRows and so on. So you may need first to check what type of row e.Row is, or you can revise your application logic.